# How to update/sign many JARs files in ANT

Tags: java, ant, jar

Is there any way to sign and update **ALL** JARs in a folder/subfolders?

currently, i'm doing this:

```
    <signjar keystore="${web.etc}/key.jks" storepass="pass" alias="alias" lazy="yes" maxmemory="256m">
        <fileset dir="${docroot}/applets/subfolder/" includes="AppletName.jar" />
    </signjar>
```

and i need to update the MANIFEST in these JARs too, making the same painful work, one by one.

```
<jar update="true" file="${docroot}/applets/subfolder/AppletName.jar">
<manifest>
    (atributes)
</manifest> </jar>
```

is there any way to do these operations for *.jar files?

Comment: Use apply task with executable=jar and arg value=umf on fileset as described here => http://stackoverflow.com/a/16606976/130683 for the update part.

Answer (score 1):

hi regarding the [official documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/signjar.html), i find this :

```
<signjar destDir="signed"
    alias="testonly" keystore="testkeystore"
    storepass="apacheant"
    preservelastmodified="true">
  <path>
    <fileset dir="dist" includes="**/*.jar" />
  </path>
  <flattenmapper />
</signjar>
```

Adapt in your case it will be :

```
    <signjar 
        keystore="${web.etc}/key.jks" 
        storepass="pass" 
        alias="alias" 
        lazy="yes" 
        maxmemory="256m">
        <path>
            <fileset 
                    dir="${docroot}/applets/subfolder/"            
                    includes="*.jar" />
        </path>
    </signjar>
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine for the signjar. now i'm trying to do this with the jar update, it's not similar =/

Comment: the more simple way is to delete all the jars, rebuild them, and sing them again